# How to run a memory intensive spark streaming job using the smallest memory usage possible

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am running a job that joins two kafka topics into one topic using a value. The environment I am using only allow me to assign less than 10g ram per job, the data I am trying to join is around 500k record per topic.

I am pretty new to Spark, so I'd like to know if there is a way to minimize the memory consumption

the code:

```
val df_person: DataFrame = PERSONINFORMATION_df
      .select(from_json(expr("cast(value as string) as actualValue"), schemaPERSONINFORMATION).as("s")).select("s.*").withColumn("comsume_date", lit(LocalDateTime.now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss.SS")))).as("dfperson")

val df_candidate: DataFrame = CANDIDATEINFORMATION_df
      .select(from_json(expr("cast(value as string) as actualValue"), schemaCANDIDATEINFORMATION).as("s")).select("s.*").withColumn("comsume_date", lit(LocalDateTime.now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss.SS")))).as("dfcandidate")
```

Join topics:

```
val joined_df : DataFrame = df_candidate.join(df_person, col("dfcandidate.PERSONID") === col("dfperson.ID"),"inner").withColumn("join_date", lit(LocalDateTime.now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss.SS"))))
```

Re-structure the data

```
val string2json: DataFrame = joined_df.select($"dfcandidate.ID".as("key"),to_json(struct($"dfcandidate.ID".as("candidateID"), $"FULLNAME", $"PERSONALID",$"join_date",$"dfcandidate.PERSONID".as("personID"),$"dfcandidate.comsume_date".as("candidate_comsume_time"),$"dfperson.comsume_date".as("person_comsume_time"))).cast("String").as("value"))
```

write them to a topic

```
string2json.writeStream.format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "xxx:9092")
      .option("topic", "mergedinfo")
      .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/producer/checkpoints")
      .option("failOnDataLoss", false)
      .start()
      .awaitTermination()
```

the run command:

```
spark-submit --class taqasi_spark.App --master yarn ./spark_poc-test_memory.jar --executor-memory 10g --driver-memory 10g --executor-memory 10g  --deploy-mode cluster
```

Comment: Spark itself is a batch processing library and can't handle cases like these well. You are better off using `Apache Flink` or `Spark Streaming`

Comment: I am indeed using Spark Streaming, the DataFrame I am reading are kafka streams @sinanspd